# Error in running MapReduce job on Haoop Cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I ran a wordcount MapReduce Program, and some of the tasks failed with the status 126. Seems that there is no logs at all on the server side. Any idea what this mean?

```
Thanks.

java.lang.Throwable: Child Error
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:271)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Task process exit with nonzero status of 126.
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskRunner.run(TaskRunner.java:258)
```

Comment: Look inside your log file and repost the error.

Comment: Please examine the tasktracker log file on the node where this failure occured

Comment: I checked the log file on that tasktracker, there is some EOF exception. Thank u, it helped.